# nodejs GraphicsMagick (gm) passing stream to .composite()

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick, gm

Using Expressjs with gm (GraphicsMagick) module.

I would like to use a stream as the input to .composite().

Is this possible, or is there any way of doing this?

I can composite using a path or a variable containing a path to an image, but I would like to pass in a stream instead (myStream).

Example:

```
var myStream = fs.createReadStream('topimage.png');

var resultStream = gm('/images/background.png')
                        .composite(myStream)
                        .gravity('Center')
                        .geometry('-1020+520')
                        .stream();
```

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: @HamzaBaig No, I did not find a solution to this. Is this something you are looking for too?

Comment: Yes, i've been looking for a solution but to no avail. So i settled with creating a tmp file every time and then using it instead.